# How to Make fixed HTML box on side of webpage? very basic box?

Tags: html

I just want a basic html box that is completely position to the left side of the webpage and overlays everything, and just to be a certain color with vertical text as demonstrated in this picture: http://postimg.org/image/l12q7hxqn/

Can this be done with HTML? I assume it would be a very basic code but I dont know what. If someone could make the code, I could figure out how to adjust the dimensions & color.

Thanks

Comment: it is better to use an image

Comment: You can have look at this http://jsfiddle.net/mark69_fnd/PWRDa/

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `vertical-align: middle;` and `float:left` properties in css

Comment: Ya, but I was hoping for someone to give me an example of an actual code, of what it would look like so I can copy n paste

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place where you can ask "I want this, but I'm too lazy to think, so just give me code I can copy and paste". This is a _help_ resource, not a free code resource

Answer (score 0):

You can do the formatting by putting the html box inside `<td>` and `<tr>` tags and another set of `<td>`,`<tr>` tags with nothing inside them. With this, a table with one row and two table data will be created and the html box will be treated as a left-most table data of that particular table.